# Are hash onions inherently sequential?

Tags: complexity-theory

An open problem in complexity theory is whether [NC equals P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)).

I'm somewhat confused because I would have thought that it's obvious that NC != P because of hash onions. A hash onion is when you start with some input $i$ and repeatedly hash $n$ times:

$$H(i), H(H(i)), ..., H^n(i)$$

Given an input $i$ the amount of work to compute $H^n(i)$ is $O(n)$ so hash onions are part of P. And because the hash function $H$ acts like a random oracle you can't do better than sequential queries to $H$, therefore hash onions are not part of NC.

What am I missing?

Comment: What _exactly_ is the input to your "hash onion" problem? If the input is $i$ and $n$, both in binary, then the algorithm you suggest takes exponential time in the length of the input.

Comment: Ok fine :) Replace $H^n$ by $H^{\log(n)}$. Now the algorithm takes time linear in the length of the input.

Comment: Or just write $n$ in unary. It be good to make it explicit in the question.

Comment: Do you mean "replace $H^N$ by $H^{log(i)}$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all engineering purposes, you are right, if you choose a cryptographically strong hash function $H$.

For theoretical purposes, nope.  There's no proof.  Your argument is based on unproven assumptions, hence it can't be regarded as a proof that NC $\ne$ P.  In particular, we don't know of any hash function $H$ that we can prove is cryptographically strong, or that we can prove is inherently sequential when repeated like this. All of our hash functions are either heuristic (we think they are good but we have no ironclad proof) or are based on other assumptions (such as that factoring is hard; something we suspect but have no proof of).  And assuming that $H$ behaves like a random oracle is an unproven assumption.  So if you're a theorist and what you care about is *proving* that NC $\ne$ P, none of these count as a suitable proof.

Personally, I do consider them pretty good evidence that in all likelihood NC $\ne$ P... but it's not a proof.

Comment: Ok. Would it be fair that in the random oracle model NC $\ne$ P trivially, but it's still an open question in the standard model?

Comment: @Randomblue, sounds right to me.

Comment: And as a consequence, if P = NC, it's impossible for any hash to satisfy these assumptions?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, that sounds right to me too.